# Giving CSV as a datasource to chart

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, charts

In my application I'm taking a CSv file from user with the help of OpenFileDialog control.After I get the CSV I give it to a datagridview as a datasource.
Here is the code for taking the CSV :

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "|*.csv";
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbCSVPath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

And this is the code for giving the CSV to datagridview as a datasource:

```
private void btnCsvUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dgCSVData.DataSource = GetDataTableFromCSVFile(tbCSVPath.Text);
        chart1.DataSource = dgCSVData;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Import CSV File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private static DataTable GetDataTableFromCSVFile(string csvfilePath)
{
    DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csvfilePath))
    {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        foreach (string column in colFields)
        {
            DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
            datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
            csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
        }
        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fieldData[i] == "")
                {
                    fieldData[i] = null;
                }
            }
            csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
        }
    }
    return csvData;
}
```

My CSV files are conversion of BLG files.I also do this job in another form in my application.Now what I get so much confused and couldn't do is I want to show the values of CSV in a chart.The CSV is going to be dynamic and change all the time and I couldn't find anything and don't have so much clue about how to do this.I will be so glad if anyone help me doing this task.Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Where the Chart is located are you generating another excel where you need to create the chart dynamically  .. Also please let me know if columns are fixed only rows getting changed for the CSV ..  Or are you  using asp.net chart control

Comment: @kishoreVM Chart is located in my application at the same form where I give the CSV to datagridview as datasource.Column names and rows are also going to change,because the CSV I'm using is going to be converted from a BLG file.

Comment: @kishoreVM so what comes from BLG will set the contents of CSV

Comment: I think you can do this the same way it is done in the Following link. Once you get your data table, you can pass the datatable to  GenerateChart method  that will return you the chart control. And you add to the panel or any layout control or assign that to existing chart. In the example you can see it doesnot depend on the no of columns. If it worked please let me know i will add that as answer. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168056/Windows-Charting-Application

Comment: @kishoreVM I'm checking it right away